# iPhone: Preventing text truncation with UITableView of style UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

[image: Problem]

As you can see, both the text (left) *and* the detail text (right) have been truncated. How can I ensure only the detail text on the right is truncated, while the text on the left remains in full?

Thanks friends.

Comment: Seems like you attached the wrong photo?

Comment: I'm responding six years late but actually it looks like imgur had a GUID collision! This did used to show the correct image! I'm kind of want to leave it up for fun, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it simply other then 1) subclassing UITableViewCell and handle layout yourself, or 2) only display x number of characters in your detail text label.

2) is what I'd do.